# Program outputs wrong info

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem**

So, my problem is that my program allows the admin to input a teacher's first and last name, and than checks if the teacher already exists in the db. If the teacher already exists in the db, the program should run: `header("location:../../admin.php?msg=Teacher already exists");`, but if the teacher doesn't exist in the db, the program should put the teacher in the db. But, when I tested the program, even though the teacher didn't exist in the db, the program ran: `header("location:../../admin.php?msg=Teacher already exists");`, instead of inserting the teacher into the db.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php 

require '../connect.php';

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

// check if inpusta are not empty
if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname)) {

    // check if teacher isn't already in the database
    $getTeacher = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM teachers
                                WHERE firstname = :firstname
                                AND lastname = :lastname");
    $getTeacher->execute(array(
        "firstname" => $firstname,
        "lastname" => $lastname,
    ));
    $getTeacher = $getTeacher->fetch();

    // if teacher doesn't exist in db
    if(!getTeacher) {

        // insert teacher into db
        echo "Success";

    } else {
        header("location:../../admin.php?msg=Teacher already exists");
    }

} else {
    header("location:../../admin.php?msg=Required inputs must be filled");
}
```

?>

Comment: `if(!getTeacher)` that's an error; it's treated as a constant. You missed the `$` if that is your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss-typed the variable $getTeacher.
`if(!getTeacher) {` should be `if(!$getTeacher) {`

Comment: Just up voted to make your reputation 50 so you can comment but its already answered in comment